# Conexão mongodb com nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Como faço a conexão com a database mongo com nodejs? Já consultei vários sitios mas não estou conseguindo fazer da maneira correta! Agradeço a quem ajudar!

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).

Segue um exemplo de como abrir a conexão

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
global.db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/neventos');
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
 console.log('=====Conexão estabelecida com sucesso=====');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log('=====Ocorreu um erro: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
 console.log('=====Conexão finalizada=====');
});
```

Nesse [link](https://github.com/juliano-nunes/exercicios_mba/blob/master/31SCJ_WebModerna/03_MongoDB/app) tem um projeto completo que utilizei mongoose para fazer a conexão.

Comment: Preciso de mais alguma coisa além de instalar o mongodb e o nodejs? É que ele dá erro na consola a dizer "require is not defined"

Comment: O Node.js é uma linguagem utilizada para server side, pelo erro que você disse que está ocorrendo, provavelmente está chamando esse arquivo js em um navegador, daí a implementação é diferente, terá que utilizar algo como o requirejs no seu projeto.

Comment: E tem que instalar o mongoose também.

Comment: Mas é necessariamente o mongoose para estabelecer a ligação a db?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar da seguinte maneira:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');


class MyConnect extends MongoClient {

  constructor(url, options) {
    super(url, options);
    this.client = null;

    this.on('insert-value', this.insertValue)
  }

async insertValue(data) {
    try {
       this.client = await this.connect()

       const collection = this.client.db('testando').collection('olhaai');
       const response = await collection.insertOne(data);

       console.log(response);
       this.client.close();
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
     }
  }
}

(new MyConnect(
    process.env.MONGOURL, 
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true 
    })
).emit('insert-value', { ola: 'fion', tudo: 'bom'});
```

Lembrando que a classe MongoCliente herda da classe EventEmitter então você pode usar o:

```
module.exports = MyConnect;
```

com isto você pode usar a sua estância da classe e chamar os ouvintes evento que estão dentro dela com o .emit('EventName', opções);

bom uso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
fiz o teste 4 vezes, você pode manipular as querys pelo ouvinte de evento, ou chamando a própria função.